# How to find is a lateinit var has been initialized via Reflection?

Tags: kotlin, reflection, kotlin-reflect, kotlin-lateinit

I want to find out via reflection if lateinit property of an object has been initialized. How do I got about doing that?

Getting the property and checking non-null results in UninitializedPropertyAccessException

```
fun Any.isAnyEntityInitialized () {
    val clazz = this.javaClass.kotlin
    val filteredEntities = clazz.declaredMemberProperties.filter {
        it.isLateinit && getDelegate(this) != null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMemberProperties
import kotlin.reflect.jvm.javaField

class Test {
    lateinit var s: String
}

fun Any.isAnyEntityInitialized(): Boolean =
    this::class.declaredMemberProperties.any { property ->
        property.isLateinit && property.javaField?.get(this) != null
    }

fun main() {
    val test = Test()
    println(test.isAnyEntityInitialized()) // prints false
    test.s = "test"
    println(test.isAnyEntityInitialized()) // prints true
}
```

Comment: The idea is perfect, but the code is not working as my expectation. The provided code will check only one property. I edited it like this.
`
fun Any.isAnyEntityInitialized(): Boolean
{
    this::class.declaredMemberProperties.forEach { property ->
        if(property.isLateinit && property.javaField?.get(this) == null)
            return false
    }

    return true
}
`

Answer (score 1):

Since Kotlin 1.2, there is already a function for that.

You can use the function: `isInitialized` [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/is-initialized.html)

Code example:

```
lateinit var key: String

fun useKey() {
    check(::key.isInitialized) { "The field 'key' must be initialized" }
    // use key safely
}
```

**Note:** `check` will throw an IllegalStateException if the variable is not initialized.